# Suggested edit rejected and replaced by identical edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16241132) I suggested an edit where the answer was quoting a webpage which is not online anymore (parashift.com). I was checking if there was a substitute and found isocpp which seems to be more or less the replacement for parashift. I also updated the formatting to make the answer more readable.

The part which the answer quoted has been slightly changed on isocpp to be more generic so while fixing the dead link I also updated the quoted content to match what the updated link provides.

My edit got rejected and replaced with an identical edit. Why did it get rejected? The reason given by the community reject

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

seems wrong since I fixed a dead link, updated formatting and adjusted content which for me doesn't count anymore as minor change.

Comment: You didn't format the code in the "What's the difference" sentence above the bullets. Though I don't get why you both felt the need to change 'Frank' to 'X'.

Comment: You were inserting those horrible "smart" quotes.  Great for typographic content, horrible for discussion of code.

Comment: I see... so why not accept and edit? The `Fred` to `X` change was because the new website also changed from `Fred` to `X` so the content from the answer would align with the new link.

Comment: @Philipp Because the reviewer disliked your edits and rejected them.

Comment: He disliked them so much he edited the answer in pretty much the same way I suggested?